# Perfomance comparison of circular mean estimators with long-tailed noise

Tags: mse, circular-statistics

I am trying to compare the performance of two estimators of the mean of a circular random variable. One of  these estimators gives estimates with lower absolute error but only for samples that are very far from the true mean, so when I compare them using the circular equivalent of the mean square error I do not see a big performance gain. Is there any standard way to compare the performance of the estimators that would not run into this problem?